# ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: javascript, process, environment-variables

I am running a k6 test and using env variables for some of the code. I keep getting this darn error though:

ReferenceError: process is not defined

I have tried using an alternate some people suggested in a similar issue using __ENV.yadda, but that did not work.

```
import http from "k6/http";

let formData = {
  client_id: "LoadTesting",
  grant_type: "blah_blah",
  scope: "Scope",
};
const messageHeaders = {
  'Content-Type': 'Client Type',
};

let user = null;
export function authorizeUser() {
  formData.client_secret = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_SECRET;
  if (!user) {
    let res = http.post(`https://localhost:44341/connect/token`, formData, { headers: messageHeaders });
    if (res.status != 200) {
      console.log('res: ', res.status);
      throw new Error("couldn't load user");
    }
    user = JSON.parse(res.body).access_token;
    return user;
  }
}
```

I just want my env variables to work!

Answer (score 1):

The environment variable in the k6 works different as for the Node.js try something as that:
https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

You can use the k6/x/dotenv extension library to do this. Please see: https://github.com/szkiba/xk6-dotenv for more information

At the start of your file:

```
import dotenv from "k6/x/dotenv";
const env = dotenv.parse(open('/path/to/your/.env'))
```

Then get your environment variables like so:

```
const yourEnvVar = env.YOUR_ENV_VAR
```

Comment: I got xk6-dotenv working only by building a custom k6 binary... Is building a custom k6 binary the only way to utilize the extension library or is there another way to use it without having to build a custom binary?

Comment: As far as I know, building the custom binary is the only way. As it is a k6 extension and therefore not built into the official k6 binary